# TypeScript Error While Using @Input()

Tags: angular, typescript, angularjs-directive

I am trying to develop an app using Angular 4. But I have received an error message while using

```
@Input('inputProducts') products: Product[];
```

The Error is

> [tslint] In the class "ProductListComponent", the directive input
>   property "products" should not be renamed.Please, consider the
>   following use "@Input() products: string" (no-input-rename).

The Error Does Not Have any Effect and My App is working fine but it is annoying and am unable to remove it. Code Snippet is Given Below:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { Product } from '../product-row/product.model';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-list',
  templateUrl: './product-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-list.component.css']
})
export class ProductListComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input('inputProducts') products: Product[];
  @Output() selectedProduct: EventEmitter<Product>;
  constructor() {
    this.selectedProduct = new EventEmitter();
  }
  clickedProduct(p: Product): boolean {
    this.selectedProduct.emit(p);
    return false;
  }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

the html part

```
<app-product-list [inputProducts]="products"></app-product-list>
```

Please Point me towards right direction to remove this error.

Comment: what is the HTML looks like please update fully

Comment: Did you read the error message before posting? It tells you what to do to get rid of the error ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's styleguide, `no-input-rename` the rule that you should set to false not to get such tslint error. `no-input-rename` is set to `true` usually when you generate your project with Angular CLI. Go to your tslint file and make it's value equal to `false`. Should look something like: `"no-input-rename": false`.

Answer (score 8):

`@Input() inputProducts: Product[];` should fix your problem.

Comment: That is actually not what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

```js
products: Product[];

@Input('inputProducts')
set productsFromInput(projects: Project[]) {
  this.products = products;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in **.eslintrc.json** file under the **rules** section add these line

```
"@angular-eslint/no-input-rename": "off"
```

//Like That

```
"overrides": [
{
  "rules" : {
    "@angular-eslint/no-input-rename": "off"
  }
}
```

]